# Log.e not working even after android.util.Log is imported

Tags: android, performance, logging, android-studio-import

Am a beginner I dont understand, Why its not working even i imported android.util.Log. I am using android studio.

```
package com.sai.myapplication;
import android.util.Log; // showing full gray 

public class Fan {

protected String fanName;
protected boolean isOn;

public String getFanName() {
    return this.fanName;
}
public void BreakFan(){
    log.e(getFanName(),"BANg, CRASH!......OOPPs");// "log" is showing in red
}
}
```

Comment: change `log` to `Log` ( uppercase L)

Answer (score 0):

Log 'L' show be Caps. Please check it. You are using wrong one.

Log.e(getFanName(),"BANg, CRASH!......OOPPs");// "log" is showing in red

Answer (score 0):

Its `Log` not **log**(with capital L). If I am not wrong **log** was giving you compile time error. So please use `Log` as below.

```
Log.e(getFanName(),"BANg, CRASH!......OOPPs");
```